# How to remove draft emails that appear inside Outlook inbox?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap, microsoft-outlook-2016

I am using Outlook 2016 to read gmail emails through IMAP. For some reasons, draft emails appear inside the inbox. How do I stop the draft emails from appearing in the inbox?

Comment: do you have any antivirus plugins for outlook installed ?

Answer (score 1):

Check under **File** -> **Options** -> **Mail** -> **Save messages** heading, and verify whether the '**Save to this folder:**' option is set to **Inbox**.
[image]

Comment: Mine is set to Drafts.